# What is the old (50's) convention on Dirac gamma matrices?

Tags: conventions, history, dirac-equation, complex-numbers, dirac-matrices

What were the standard relations for gamma matrices in the mid 50's, when 4-vectors where represented by $(x_1, x_2, x_3, ict)$? In particular the values of $\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu$
, the definition of $\bar{\psi}$ and $\gamma^5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gregor Wentzel's 1949's book, "Quantum theory of fields" defines the Dirac matrices as

\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha ^{(\nu)} &=& \alpha ^{(\nu)*}\\
\alpha ^{(\mu)} \alpha ^{(\nu)} + \alpha ^{(\nu)} \alpha ^{(\mu)} &=& 2 \delta_{\mu\nu}
\end{eqnarray}

and the gamma matrices as ($\beta$ is $\alpha^{(4)}$)

\begin{eqnarray}
\gamma^{(k)} &=& -i \beta \alpha^{(k)}\\
&=& i \alpha^{(k)} \beta\\
\gamma^{(4)} &=& \beta
\end{eqnarray}

with properties

\begin{eqnarray}
\gamma^{(\nu)} &=& \gamma^{(\nu)*}\\
\gamma^{(\mu)} \gamma^{(\nu)} + \gamma^{(\nu)} \gamma^{(\mu)} &=& 2 \delta_{\mu\nu}
\end{eqnarray}

and the adjoint spinor is

\begin{eqnarray}
\psi^\dagger = i \psi^* \beta
\end{eqnarray}

Rivier in "On the quantum theory of fields" (1953) defines the matrices by

\begin{eqnarray}
\gamma^{i} &=& \beta a^i\\
\gamma^4 &=& \beta
\end{eqnarray}

with

\begin{eqnarray}
a^i = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sigma^i\\
\sigma^i & 0
\end{pmatrix},\ \beta = \begin{pmatrix}
(1) & 0\\
0 & (1)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

with the identities

\begin{eqnarray}
[\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu]_+ &=&  2 g^{\mu\nu}
\gamma^{i+} &=& -\gamma^i\\
\gamma^{4+} &=& \gamma^4
\end{eqnarray}

The adjoint spinor is defined by

\begin{eqnarray}
\bar{\psi} = \psi^+_b \beta_{ba}
\end{eqnarray}

Morse defines them in Methods of theoretical physics (1953) as

[image]

It's harder to find uses of $\gamma^5$ (most theories were chiral), but you can check [Theory of the Fermi interaction](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2ef6/7c5216f4ac89529feaed9be0867572c59c0a.pdf) (1957), which puts it as $\gamma^5 = \gamma_x \gamma_y \gamma_z \gamma_t$, with

\begin{eqnarray}
\gamma^t = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix},\ \mathbf{\gamma} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \mathbf{\sigma}\\
- \mathbf{\sigma} & 0
\end{pmatrix},\ i\gamma^5 = -\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}